# FCM responds {"readystate":0,"responsetext":"","status":0,"statustext":"error"}

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, firebase, monaca

When sending a message with javascript FCM, {"readystate":0,"responsetext":"","status":0,"statustext":"error"} is returned by ajax .

Receiving is fine, and it works as intended in the IDE without any problems, but when I build it on iOS 15 16, I get {"readystate":0,"responsetext":"","status":0,"statustext":"error "} is returned.
As far as I checked with the debug build, there was no difference in the Payload information between the IDE and the build,
and I tried various things, but I couldn't find it.
If you have any information, please let me know.

`

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
        type: 'POST',
        headers : { Authorization : 'key='+'<key>'  },
        contentType : 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify({"to": "<token>", "notification": {"title":"Test","body":"Test"}}),
        timeout: 0,
        complete: function () {
            console.log('complete') ;
            },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(xhr) ;
            console.log(status) ;
            console.log(error) ;
            },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data) ;
            }
    });
```

`

I tried async: false, but there was almost no change
, and as far as I checked with the debug build, there was no difference in Payload information between the IDE and the build

Build environment iOS6.2.0 Xcode13 CLI 11.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I also tried rebuilding, but it didn't work.
It was solved when I created an empty project and reassembled from init.